# How do you hold a reference to parameter in a block?

Tags: objective-c, block, objective-c-blocks

I am passing a parameter to a function, and I need to hold its reference in a block. The block will be executed at a later time. If I dont hold this reference, I get invalid memory access crash when the function executes.

```
- (void)doSomethingWithParamter:(Foo *)foo
{
    [Bar setCompletionHandler:^{
        // access foo here.
    }];
}
```

I tried using the strong reference to `foo` as `__typeof(Foo) *strongFoo = weakFoo;` where `weakFoo` is `__weak __typeof(Foo) *weakFoo = foo;`

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need any of that stuff you are doing. Just access as is, e.g.

```
- (void)doSomethingWithParamter:(Foo *)foo
{
    [Bar setCompletionHandler: ^ {

       [foo doSomething];

    }];
}
```

That way the block will keep a strong reference to `foo` anyhow, you need not and should not do it.

I suspect, if you get memory trouble, it is something else, maybe the trouble is with `Bar`?